# REACT Component renders and then disappears

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, json, amazon-web-services

I have only one function that first gets the list of devices. the list is a JSON array. then the function loops over each element and request the shadow.

The function builds a new array using the device properties and the shadow property

The REACT page renders and show the data for a second, and then it disappears.

If I modify the getShadow function to just return the list of devices (without shadows), the page renders just fine. But the problem starts when I build the new array using the shadow data from each device.

Any idea what am I missing here?

many thanks

here is the code

````
async function getShadows() { 

    const listThings_command = new ListThingsCommand({});

    const data = await iotClient.send(listThings_command);  /* First get the list of things */ 
    const things = data.things;

    let devices_list = [];  // to store the final array with data to render

    let shadowRequests = things.map (thing => {   /* List calls to get shadow for each thing */ 

      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        const getThingShadow_command = new GetThingShadowCommand({thingName: thing.thingName}); /** get device shadow */ 

        iotDataPlaneClient.send(getThingShadow_command).then(
          (data) => {

            const string_data = new TextDecoder('utf-8').decode(data.payload);  /* Decode payload as it is returned in Uint8Array format*/ 
            const shadow_data = JSON.parse(string_data);

            var deviceInfo = {  /* Create a new object to store required device info*/ 
              thingName : thing.thingName,
              thingTypeName: thing.thingTypeName,
              thingArn : thing.thingArn,
              shadow : shadow_data.state.reported
            };

            resolve(deviceInfo);
          },
          (error) => {

            reject(error);
          }
        ); 
      })
    })

    Promise.all(shadowRequests).then((data) => {
      data.forEach (res => {  /* loop over each promise */ 
        if (res) {
            devices_list.push(res); /* add the data as a new element in the array*/ 
        }
      })
    }
    )

    return devices_list;

  }; 
 
  function Home (){

    const [mydevices, updateMydevices] = React.useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
      getShadows().then(data => updateMydevices(data)); 
    }, []);    


    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Dashboard</h1> 
        <div>
          <h4>Devices List</h4>
          <ListGroup id="device_list">
              {
                mydevices.map((device, key) => {
                  return (
                    <ListGroup.Item key = {key}> 
                    <div>{device.thingName} </div>
                    </ListGroup.Item>
                  )
                })
              }
            </ListGroup>
        </div> 
      </div>
    );
  }
```
````

Comment: In your code `getShadows` always return empty array, `devices_list` never has any value in it. The function returns and only then `Promise.all(shadowRequests).then` is executed.

Comment: thanks @JakubKotrs can you give me an idea on how to fix that? I'm pretty new to REACT and node.js

Comment: Somebody already posted an answer. Since you are using Promises, you need to await them before returning the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) here, the devices list will be returned before the shadow requests are complete. So it will always be an empty array. You can try something like this.

```
try {
    const data = await Promise.all(shadowRequests);
    data.forEach (res => {  /* loop over each promise */ 
        if (res) {
            devices_list.push(res); /* add the data as a new element in the array*/ 
        }
    })
}
catch(err) {
     //handle error
}
return devices_list;
```